# Can I automate Avast Business Antivirus with pywinauto?

Tags: python, pywinauto

I often have to click through the Avast Business Antivirus gui to toggle a specific setting. I want to automate this process using pywinauto but I'm having a hard time navigating the application launch window. The image below shows Avast at launch, I want to click the 'Menu' button (and subsequently other buttons but I think I can get there if I can figure out the Menu button first).

[image: Avast Launch]

Using python 3.6.8 / pywinauto 0.6.8:

from pywinauto.application import Application

```
app = Application(backend='uia').start('C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\AvastUI.exe').connect(title='Avast Business Antivirus',timeout=100)
app.AvastBusinessAntivirus.print_control_identifiers()
```

Returns:

```
Control Identifiers:

Dialog - 'Avast Business Antivirus'    (L169, T143, R1431, B985) 
['Dialog', 'Avast Business Antivirus', 'Avast Business AntivirusDow")
   | 
   | Pane - 'AvastChromiumWindow'    (L169, T143, R1431, B985)   
   | ['Pane', 'AvastChromiumWindow', 'AvastChromiumWindowPane', 'Pane0', 'Pane1']
   | child_window(title="AvastChromiumWindow", control_type="Pane")
   |    | 
   |    | Pane - ''    (L169, T143, R1431, B985)
   |    | ['Pane2']
   |    |    | 
2, B986)
   |    |    | ['Pane3', 'Chrome Legacy Window', 'Chrome Legacy WindowPane']
   |    |    | child_window(title="Chrome Legacy Window", auto_id="1002608416", control_type="Pane")
```

I don't see anything identifying 'Notification'/'Menu'/etc. So I tried using 'win32' instead of 'uia' but got the error below:

```
Control Identifiers:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\webshare.py", line 4, in <module>
    app.AvastBusinessAntivirus.print_control_identifiers()       
  File "C:\Users\greg_\Desktop\projects\avast_auto\.venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 689, in print_control_identifiers
    print_identifiers([this_ctrl, ])
  File "C:\Users\greg_\Desktop\projects\avast_auto\.venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 660, in print_identifiers
    if hasattr(ctrl.element_info, 'automation_id'):
  File "C:\Users\greg_\Desktop\projects\avast_auto\.venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\win32_element_info.py", line 201, in automation_id
    remote_mem = RemoteMemoryBlock(self, size=length*2)
  File "C:\Users\greg_\Desktop\projects\avast_auto\.venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\remote_memory_block.py", line 112, in __init__
    if hex(self.mem_address) == '0xffffffff80000000' or hex(self.mem_address).upper() == '0xFFFFFFFF00000000':
TypeError: 'NoneType' object cannot be interpreted as an integer 
Exception ignored in: <bound method RemoteMemoryBlock.__del__ of 
<pywinauto.remote_memory_block.RemoteMemoryBlock object at 0x00000182616217B8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\greg_\Desktop\projects\avast_auto\.venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\remote_memory_block.py", line 170, in __del__    self.CleanUp()
  File "C:\Users\greg_\Desktop\projects\avast_auto\.venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\remote_memory_block.py", line 147, in CleanUp    self.CheckGuardSignature()
  File "C:\Users\greg_\Desktop\projects\avast_auto\.venv\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\remote_memory_block.py", line 286, in CheckGuardSignature
    c_void_p(self.mem_address + self.size),
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```